# Uninitialized local variable “m” used

Tags: c, visual-studio, oop

```
medication createMedication(char name[], float concentration, int quantity, float price)
{
    medication m;
    strcpy(m.name, name);
    m.concentration = concentration;
    m.price = price;
    m.quantity = quantity;

    return m;
}
```

I get the `uninitialized local variable "m" used` error for line 10(where the `strcpy()` function is) and I don't know why.

The header file that it's using is:

```
#pragma once


typedef struct {
    char* name;
    float concentration;
    int quantity;
    float price;
}medication;

medication createMedication(char name[], float concentration, int quantity, float price);
char* getName(medication *m);
float getConcentration(medication *m);
int getQuantity(medication *m);
float getPrice(medication *m);
```

And the whole file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "medication.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

medication createMedication(char name[], float concentration, int quantity, float price)
{
    medication m;
    strcpy(m.name, name);
    m.concentration = concentration;
    m.price = price;
    m.quantity = quantity;

    return m;
}

char* getName(medication* m)
{
    return m->name;
}

float getConcentration(medication* m)
{
    return m->concentration;
}

float getPrice(medication* m)
{
    return m->price;
}


int getQuantity(medication* m)
{
    return m->quantity;
}

void toString(medication m, char str[])
{
    sprintf(str, "Medication %s: Concentration:%f , Price:%f ,Quantity:%d", m.name,m.concentration,m.price,m.quantity);
```

Comment: what is the definition of the typedef struct medication?

Comment: what is the contents of the home grown header file: `medication.h`?

Comment: the function: `createMedication()` would be much better written to have a return type of : `medication *`  and the line `medication m;`  be replaced with: `medication *m = malloc( sizeof( medication );`  (of course then check for failure of the call to `malloc()`)  Then all assignments to the fields would use `->` rather than `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    float concentration;
    int quantity;
    float price;
}medication;
```

Here you have declared the char pointer vaiable "name" but you you haven't allocated memory for this pointer. So it may be pointing to some garbage value or address. You have to allocate memory before copying any data to this pointer "name". After declaration of "m" variable you have to allocate memory for "name" pointer.

```
medication m;
m.name = (char *)malloc(size);
```

Comment: I worked late and I totally forgot to allocate memory, and not only here... thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

`name` variable inside `medication struct` is culprit in this case.

in `G++` this code works fine. but Visual Studio Compiler does not work.

I have changed `char *name` to `char name[256 {or any size}]`.

This should work

Comment: Neither in g++ :) Using an unallocated pointer is undefined behaviour, It can work or fail.

Comment: Yep , forgot to allocate the memory. I just did it now dynamically. Thanks for the help!